# Why is the function is not working properly when I take the value from the user and stroe in a global variable?

Tags: javascript, function, dom, scope

I,m making a small javascript project (guess the number) which takes a value from the user through a textbox

```html
<input type="number" class="numebr-holder" placeholder="?" />
```

storing it in a variable called numberHolder

```js
const numberHolder = Number(document.querySelector(".numebr-holder").value);
```

and compare it with a random number from 1-20 stored in a variable named secretNumber

```js
const secretNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
```

which I log it to the console to test the function.
There are three possible results no number when the textbox (numebr-holder) is empty,  too low when the value is less than secretNumber,  too high when the value is bigger than secretNumber, or ✅ correct when the value matches the secretNumber, and they are shown in a paragraph called message

```html
<p class="message">start guessing...</p>
```

The code is working properly when I declare numberHolder inside the function (Local scope) and shows the correct answer.

```js
// global socpe
let message = document.querySelector(".message");
const checkBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-check");
const secretNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
console.log("the random number is = " + secretNumber);

let checkTheNumber = function () {
  //local scope
  const numberHolder = Number(document.querySelector(".numebr-holder").value);

  if (!numberHolder) {
    message.textContent = "no number";
    console.log("no number");
  } else if (numberHolder < secretNumber) {
    message.textContent = " too low";
    console.log("low " + numberHolder);
  } else if (numberHolder > secretNumber) {
    message.textContent = " too high";
    console.log("high " + numberHolder);
  } else {
    message.textContent = "✅ correct";
    console.log("correct " + numberHolder);
  }
};

checkBtn.addEventListener("click", checkTheNumber);
```

but when the numberHolder is decleared in the global scope it stores only the first value have been putting in the textbox and even if I change the value in the textbox its still the same until I refresh the page then it stores the value before refreshing and so on until I refresh again to change the value.
Please what is the difference between declaring the numberHolder in the local scope and global scope and why it's only storing the first value when it declared in the global scope ??

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual code that _isn't_ working. We can't tell you what the problem is if we have to guess what that code looks like

Answer (score 0):

Well you declare `const numberHolder = Number(document.querySelector(".numebr-holder").value);` globally, it only reads the value of the input element once on page load and never changes again. It does **not** track changes in the value; it is just like assigning a string to any variable.

On the other hand, declaring the variable inside the `checkTheNumber` function means that the inut element's value is read **each time** the button is clicked, as that is a click event handler function for `checkBtn`.

Comment: thanks for your attention, but isn't it supposed to read the variable each time even if it was global because inside the function every time the event happens it calls the function which go and check the numberHolder value each time ??

Comment: @yui No, the value is set once. Reading the value isn't going to change it. After the value is set, it's not linked to the input element's value at all.